# Django: Use limit_choices_to to limit choices in Admin menu

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model in Django:

```
class Task(models.Model):  
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)  
    content = models.OneToOneField(ContentDataSet)
```

How can I use option `limit_choices_to=` for  `content` field if I want to show only not yet assigned `ContentDataSet` options AND already assigned to this Task options in user/admin in standart drop-down choicelist?

I tried to use `limit_choices_to = {'task__isnull':True}`, but in that case I can't see already assigned to this Task `content` options.

`limit_choices_to = models.Q(task__isnull=True) | models.Q(task=self)` is not working because `self` is not defined

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with limit_choices_to. 
But you can use two different approaches that work OK:

1) For `ForeignKeys` you can use `formfield_for_foreignkey` to override the queryset in your ModelAdmin like this:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return super(UserOwnerProtectorModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    if db_field.name == "task":
        # This next line only shows owned objects
        # but you can write your own query!
        kwargs["queryset"] = db_field.related_model.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

2) And as a second choice here is an example that overrides the field queryset which can help you on the OneToOne field:
[Django ForeignKey limit_choices_to a different ForeignKey id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578559/django-foreignkey-limit-choices-to-a-different-foreignkey-id)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Limit_choices_to is a Q object.
In docs you have an example of making similar restriction on ForeignKey: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

More about queries is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: When I use `limit_choices_to = {'task__isnull':True}`, I can see only 'fresh' `content` which are not assigned to anything. In that case I can't edit `Task` because I can't see already assigned to this `Task` options.