# Django ForeignKey limit_choices_to a different ForeignKey id

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to limit Django Admin choices of a ForeignKey using `limit_choices_to`, but I can't figure out how to do it properly.

This code does what I want if the category id is 16, but I can't figure out how to use the current category id rather than hard-coding it.

```
class MovieCategory(models.Model):    
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    prefix = models.ForeignKey('Prefix', limit_choices_to={'category_id': '16'},
                               blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Movie Number', max_digits=2,
                                 blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=0)
```

Is it possible to refer to the id of the category `ForeignKey` somehow?

Comment: If you're happy with just raising a validation error, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/37946885/247696

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After hours of reading semi related questions I finally figured this out.

You can't self reference a Model the way I was trying to do so there is no way to make Django act the way I wanted using `limit_choices_to` because it can't find the id of a different `ForeignKey` in the same model.

This can apparently be done if you change the way Django works, but a simpler way to solve this was to make changes to admin.py instead.

Here is what this looks like in my models.py now:

```
# models.py
class MovieCategory(models.Model):    
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    prefix = models.ForeignKey('Prefix', blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Movie Number', max_digits=2,
                                 blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=0)
```

I simply removed `limit_choices_to` entirely.
I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133455/django-limit-choices-to-doesnt-work-on-manytomanyfield) with the solution posted by Kyle Duncan. The difference though is that this uses `ManyToMany` and not `ForeignKey`. That means I had to remove `filter_horizontal = ('prefix',)` under my class `MovieCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):` as that is only for `ManyToMany` fields.

In admin.py I had to add `from django import forms` at the top to create a form. This is how the form looks:

```
class MovieCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MovieCategory
        fields = ['prefix']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MovieCategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['prefix'].queryset = Prefix.objects.filter(
                                        category_id=self.instance.category.id)
```

And my `AdminModel`:

```
class MovieCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Admin Class for 'Movie Category'.
    """
    fieldsets = [
        ('Category',      {'fields': ['category']}),
        ('Movie',         {'fields': ['movie']}),
        ('Prefix',        {'fields': ['prefix']}),
        ('Number',        {'fields': ['number']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('category', 'movie', 'prefix', 'number')
    search_fields = ['category__category_name', 'movie__title', 'prefix__prefix']
    form = MovieCategoryForm
```

This is exactly how Kyle describes it in his answer, except I had to add `fields = ['prefix']` to the Form or it wouldn't run. If you follow his steps and remember to remove `filter_horizontal` and add the fields you're using it should work.

Edit: This solution works fine when editing, but not when creating a new entry because it can't search for the category id when one doesn't exits. I am trying to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Because I've been pretty busy I've coded around the problem of creating new items. I currently create new items within the category model rather than this one and since Prefix has a foreignkey linking it to that the problem is eliminated for me.

If I do find a way to solve this I will update my solution, but as it stands this does what it needs to for my application.

Comment: where did you defined Prefix model? or what is this? `self.fields['prefix'].queryset = Prefix.objects.filter(
                                        category_id=self.instance.category.id)`

Answer (score 9):

Another approach, if you don't want to add a custom ModelForm, is to handle this in your ModelAdmin's `get_form()` method. This was preferable for me because I needed easy access to the request object for my queryset.

```
class StoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(StoryAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

        form.base_fields['local_categories'].queryset = LocalStoryCategory.\
            objects.filter(office=request.user.profile.office)

        return form
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that `limit_choices_to` supports "[Either a dictionary, a Q object, or a callable returning a dictionary or Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)" and should theoretically support any lookup that can be done using django's queryset filtering. A potential solution would then be filtering based on some property of the category that you control such as a slug field.

```py
class MovieCategory(models.Model):    
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    prefix = models.ForeignKey('Prefix', blank=True, null=True,
                               limit_choices_to=Q(category__slug__startswith='movie'))
    number = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Movie Number', max_digits=2,
                                 blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=0)
```

Comment: How can i use the limit_choices_to referencing to a parent id?

Comment: @Jcc.Sanabria If you had a `Book` belongs to `Author` relationship with a foreignkey set on `Book` (`Book.author_id`) and you wanted to filter your book choices to those belonging to a particular author, you should be able to do `limit_choices_to=Q(author_id=1)`. If you instead have a `ManyToMany('myapp.Book')` field on `Author`, it would be something like `limit_choices_to=Q(author__id=1)` because you are using a reverse accessor. For more, read about the [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field. But I dont recommend hard-coding filters by id.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and your self-answer helped me get started.  But I also found another post ([question-12399803](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399803/how-to-check-if-a-key-in-kwargs-exists)) that completed the answer, that is, how to filter when creating a new entry.

In views.py

```
form = CustomerForm(groupid=request.user.groups.first().id)
```

In forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'groupid' in kwargs:
        groupid = kwargs.pop('groupid')
    else:
        groupid = None
    super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not groupid:
        groupid = self.instance.group.id
    self.fields['address'].queryset = Address.objects.filter(group_id=groupid)
```

So, whether adding a new customer or updating an existing customer, I can click on a link to go add a new address that will be assigned to that customer.

This is my first answer on StackOverflow.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Will the person who down-voted me leave me a comment telling me why?

Comment: You could probably replace the `if/else` block by `groupid = kwargs.pop('groupid', None)`, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure why are you doing this. But I think  there's easier way to set category for "MovieCategory" in views.py.

For example if you have urls:

```
path('category/<int:prefix_pk>/create', views.MovieCategoryCreateView.as_view(), name='movie_category_create'),
```

And then you can use prefix_pk in views.py:

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    prefix = get_object_or_404(Prefix, id=self.kwargs['prefix_pk'])
    form = MovieCategoryForm(request.POST)

        if not form.is_valid():
            ctx = {'form': form, 'prefix ': prefix }
            return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

        movie_category = form.save(commit=False)
        movie_category.prefix = prefix 
        movie_category.save()
    return redirect(reverse...)
```