# How to filter the options for a ForeignKey based on an other ForeignKey

Tags: django

I need to filter the options for a ForeignKey based on an other ForeignKey.

```
class LabValue(models.Model):

    measurement = models.ForeignKey(
        'LabMeasurement', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    unit = models.ForeignKey(
        LabMeasurementUnit,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'parameter__id': self.measurement.parameter.id},
    )
```

How can I retrieve `self.measurement.parameter.id`? If I manually enter an ID instead of `self.measurement.parameter.id` like for example "1" the query works.

```
  def __str__(self):
        return str(self.measurement.parameter.id)
```

also works as desired and returns e. g. 1 as result

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578559/django-foreignkey-limit-choices-to-a-different-foreignkey-id) help? It seems a self reference like that isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, not due to Django's ORM, but due to the way the database itself works. `measurement` is a `ForeignKey`, so it's a relationship between two tables. But relationships between tables don't deal with filtering.

Thus, you will have to implement this at the level of the forms which update the model, or, alternatively, override the model's `save` function and throw an error if the desired expectation is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

For a very clear answer: You can't do that.
Explanation:
It's a django model when you create model object/save then only your `model object` is created and on that time valid foreign key of specified instance is to be passed, so giving a limit to specific choices to model directly is not possible you need to handle it from view.

So if you have handle the choices of option in `view` but as of alternatively you can override `clean()` method to raise errors.

in model you can use clean method as below:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.measurement.parameter.id == 1:
        # .. do whatever you want to write if this condition happens
        pass
    elif self.measurement.parameter.id in [1,2,3,4,55,6]: # or just pass set of ids, statically or with queryset
        # .. code
    else:
        raise Exception("Unexpected selection of choice!!!")
```